# SAS Find() with an Array

Tags: arrays, sas

Why doesn't the following code return the only row available in my data lines statement?

```
data lines;
input a $ b $ c $ d $ e $ f $;
datalines;
word yes no maybe so blah
;
run;

data tst;
set lines;

array memo{6} a b c d e f;

do i = 1 to dim(memo);

if find(memo{i},"y","i");

end;

run;
```

There should be hits on variables `b` and `d` based on the character variable `y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that `if condition;` is equivalent to `if not condition then delete;`. As soon as SAS hits the first non-matching word, it executes the delete statement and stops processing the current observation. Try `if condition then output;` instead.

Now you'll get two rows in the resulting output dataset. If you only want at most 1 row, then consider setting a flag variable, e.g.

```
data tst;
set lines;
array memo{6} a b c d e f;
flag = 0;
do i = 1 to dim(memo);
if find(memo{i},"y","i") then flag = 1;
end;
if flag;
run;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!